# Increase the amount of connections in my server MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, vb6, database-connection, windows-server-2012

I have aplications that connect to a remote server (MySQL 5.5 on Windows Server 2012), at first I started receiving "too many connections" message which I solved by increasing MAX_CONNECTION value in my.inf to 500, then I start getting "can't create new thread" message so I decrease decrease timeouts to avoid idle connections using a socket, which didn't completely work. Now I get odd messages like 'file not found', as soon as I restart the service I stop getting the messages and everything works correctly.

The problem occurs when the server reaches around 170 connections at the same time.

Is there some configuration I'm missing?, I really don't know what info you need to give me a hint to fix this. I mean, there are servers that accept a lot morw of connections at the same time, right? waht I'm missing.

RAM and CPU of the system dosen't reach 35-40% at max connections (170).

Edit: Error occur at 2 'places', when running a query or at the attempt of conennection, it's like the MySQL service rejects the attempt. VB6 is the language used in the client app (ODBC connector). The app opens, executes and closes the connection.

Note: I have full control over client app and server config.

Comment: Where are the errors actually occurring? What role does VB6 play?

Comment: Error occur at 2 'places', when running a query or at the attempt of conennection, it's like the MySQL service rejects the attempt. VB6 is the language used in the client app (ODBC connector). The app opens, executes and closes the connection.